# Цикл формирования списка из собственных значений (Python)

Tags: python, циклы, список

Необходимо создать цикл для генерации списка, в котором каждое последующее значение формируется из предыдущего
Внизу приведен **пример** алгоритма

```
var = 'a'
list = [var, list[0] + 'b', list[1] + 'c', list [2] + 'd']
```

Выход из цикла после формирования 4 значений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = ['a']
for _ in range(3):
    l.append(l[-1] + chr(ord(l[-1][-1]) + 1))

print(l)  # → ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.accumulate('abcd'))
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd']
```